# If $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, then $f(T_\alpha) = T_{f(\alpha)}$ where $T_\alpha (x) = \alpha x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

**Problem:** If $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, then $f(T_\alpha) = T_{f(\alpha)}$ where $T_\alpha (x) = \alpha x$ and $T_\alpha: \text{span}\{1,u,u^2, \ldots u^{n-1}\} \longrightarrow \text{span}\{1,u,u^2, \ldots u^{n-1}\}$ where $u\in \mathbb C$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.  The degree of the minimal polynomial of $u$ is $n$.

**Attempt:**  I think we need to show that $f(T_\alpha)(x) = T_{f(\alpha)}(x)$ for all $x\in \text{span}\{1,u,u^2, \ldots u^{n-1}\}$.

If $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, then $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_mx^m$ for some rational coefficients $m_i$. Then $f(T_\alpha)(x) = a_0 + a_1(\alpha x) + \cdots + a_m(\alpha x)^m$ while $T_{f(\alpha)}(x) = (a_0 + a_1\alpha + \cdots + a_m\alpha ^m)x$.

**Question:** How could these two results equal to each other? Or maybe I'm supposed to understand $T_\alpha$ as a matrix?

Comment: What is $\alpha$ allowed to be?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The domain is the span of $\{1,u,u^2, ..., u^{n-1}\}$ where $n$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $u$.

Comment: That is $T_\alpha$. **What is $\alpha$?** I don't understand the problem. Please state it in English words also. For example: "Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with rational coefficients, then ... [[what?]]"